# How can I handle error in Tizen Native app using C language?

Tags: c, tizen, tizen-native-app

in the C language there isn't the statement try/catch.
How can I handle the errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I totally agree with @tmlen and more added for the Tizen specific,

You can catch a error with `get_last_error()` if the error is originated from Tizen Native API.

refer: https://developer.tizen.org/development/api-references/native-application?redirect=/dev-guide/latest/org.tizen.native.mobile.apireference/group__CAPI__COMMON__ERROR.html

```
int get_last_result (void);
char* get_error_message (int err);
```

And errors from EFL can caught `with eina_error_get()`/`eina_error_msg_get()`

but unfortunately Tizen 2.4 does not support eina error functions. it support only error type. (I can't understand about EFL guys in samsung...)

Answer (score 2):

C libraries use different mechanisms for error handling:

The return value of each function may contain an error value. The caller then needs to verify, after each function call, that the return value indicates a non-error state. For example most functions in `<unistd.h>`.

Some use a global variable which is set to a non-zero value when an error occured. For example, on failure, `fopen` sets `errno` (global variable from C standard library) to an error value, and also returns `-1` instead of a file descriptor. This is also part of the C standard, see: http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/error/errno.

Finally exception handling like in C++ may be simulated using [`longjmp`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/program/longjmp): The calles first calls [`setjmp`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/program/setjmp) at a given place in code. The library function, when it fails, then jumps directly to that place using `longjmp`. For example `libpng` does this, as described in http://www.libpng.org/pub/png/libpng-manual.txt. But there are several difficulties with this.